# Why is $\langle \nabla^2 f(0,0) h, h\rangle > 0$ for every point $h \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ not sufficient to conclude there's a minimum at $(0,0)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Why is $\langle \nabla^2 f(0,0) h, h\rangle > 0$ for every point $h \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ not sufficient to conclude there's a minimum at $(0,0)$?

Why do we also require $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0) = 0$?

I can't think of any counterexamples, and it makes intuitive sense to consider $(0,0)$ a minimum with just the first condition.

Comment: The answers are in the form of classical theorems to be found in any multivariable-calculus text.

Comment: What do you mean by "intuitive sense"?

Comment: Intuitively, I think of $\langle \nabla^2 f(0,0) h, h\rangle > 0$ to be a concave up graph, but in multi-dimensions. So usually concave up means minimum if you draw one in one-dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: $\langle \nabla^2 f(0,0) h, h\rangle=0$, if $h=0.$

Let $f(x,y):=x^2+y^2+x+y$. Then we have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0) = 1$ and $\langle \nabla^2 f(0,0) h, h\rangle > 0$ for all $h \in \mathbb R^2$ with $h \ne 0.$

$f$ does not have a (local) minimum at $(0,0).$